# Spider identification please

Tags: species-identification, speciation

[image: enter image description here]([![enter image description here]
Can someone tell me which spider this is please? I've found a few of them in my home in North-London, are they poisonous?

Comment: Can you please add where you actually live?

Comment: Im North London. Also this one is yellow/brownish with black markings but I have found others with a darker purple back..

Comment: I have taken to color correct your image so the spider can be identified easier.

Comment: @Chris your color correct makes the spider look green on both of my screens. I'd suggest having at it again :p

Answer (score 1):

It think this spider is a Tegenaria domestica also known as the barn funnel weaver in North America and the domestic house spider in Europe. See [here](https://bugguide.net/node/view/1067790) or [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tegenaria_domestica) (picture taken from the first link):

[image]

They are not poisonous and usually avoid confrontations, but can bite.

Comment: That's really informative, thank you for your help.

Comment: Does this species ever have a greenish hue to it, or are you putting that down to the OP's lighting?

Comment: @rotaredom I think this is due to the image. I have corrected the color already, have a look into the edit history to see the original version.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Looks like you've got it nailed, then.

Comment: I'm not convinced this is the same species, actually.

Comment: Its my fault with the colour, i captured it in a red plastic pot but tried to get a bit of white paper inside for the pic.  It was a yellowish/brown with dark black markings

Comment: Hi, I'm afraid this definitely is not a Tegenaria and definitely is a Scytodes.  Look at the long, spindly, almost delicate legs, and the very odd carapace.  The 'Rohrschach Blot' markings on the carapace are quite different from the wavy lines on the Tegenaria carapace as well.  Scytodes are slow-moving spiders of closets and quiet areas, rather like their distant cousins the Recluses.  Quite harmless, though, as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

Very nice, indeed!  This is a Spitting Spider (one of the Scytodes species, but I'm not sure which is most likely over in the UK).  That's a good photo, by the way.  This spider is easily told in the wild by its odd-shaped, domed carapace, with the 'Rohrschach-blot' design around the edge, and the spindly, banded legs.  It's a slow-moving, very mild-mannered spider, with one of the more fascinating methods of catching prey:  basically it spits a sticky saliva in zigzags that restrains the potential food, then rambles up and bites it.
I include a photo and a couple of links for your enjoyment - using a familiar species from the US, Scytodes thoracica.

https://bugguide.net/node/view/3347

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LaP52uKg2pU

[image: Scytodes thoracica - Spitting Spider]